# Fatal error detected in Eclipse when using Xuggle

Tags: java, video-capture, exceptions, frame

I was trying to get frames from a video using `Xuggle 5.4`. The IDE which I use is `Eclipse Juno`.The last time (which was roughly one months back) when I tried, I got the frames with a gap of 5 seconds, but today when I tried to run the code I got the below error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ee76520, pid=4340, tid=7344
#
# JRE version: 7.0_09-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle1062976990104623257.dll+0x736520]  Java_com_xuggle_ferry_FerryJNI_SWIGRefCountedTesterUpcast+0x66f005
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Eclipse workspaces\Eclipse Juno\VideoSteganography\hs_err_pid4340.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

When I googled this, I found similar similar problems, but i failed to get any solution or cause for this problem.

What may be the reason for this? I am not able to find the native code which is the cause for the crash. I used to update Java whenever available.

My need is to get the frames from a video file, what other ways are there to get this done? Feel free to ask for detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the recent update on Java. When I switched back to the older version, it worked fine without any crashing.

Hope it will be fixed during next update.